# Ruby/Sinatra/jQuery app not running in repl.it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra, replit

My [mad libs game](https://github.com/globewalldesk/madlibs.js) (Ruby/Sinatra backend, most logic is JS/jQuery, data is stored in json files) runs fine on my Mac and my Ubuntu VirtualBox, but when I installed it on repl.it (and made a few changes that seemed indicated by their example script).

When I "start" the script [on repl.it, here](https://repl.it/@lsanger/madlibs), I get the following error message at the location where it's [supposed to show up](https://madlibs--lsanger.repl.co):

> Unable To Wake Up
>
> 30 seconds.Your repl did't wake up in time. Please try again in 30 seconds.

I've never been able to run it even once on repl.it. Any ideas about why not? I'm totally new to repl.it and I can't find any help files. It seems to be a new service.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
```

You can see https://repl.it/languages/sinatra for an example.

This is something you frequently need to do when running web servers on remote machines, since they forward requests from the public internet to this IP address.

I forked this and made the change, and although there was another error (can't find main.erb), it at least solves the issue this question is about.

Comment: Thanks, nailed it. Fixed. You can see the result here: https://madlibs--lsanger.repl.co/

I had already done that...I thought. I discovered that the root problem for me was that I had made the change in a different window from the one I started in, and repl.it apparently doesn't propagate its changes to code to multiple open windows. So the changes I was making that would have solved the problem weren't "taking."

Comment: @globewalldesk glad to help. I didn't evenn realize repl.it could run web servers, it's pretty cool